# Best FRAME replacement object? IFrame? Scrollable DIV?

Tags: iframe, asp-classic, scroll, frames

I've got a Classic ASP page full of frames and I'd like to find a cross-browser-friendly alternative. In many cases, the frame exists solely to allow the user to scroll a window of text on one side of the screen.

What's the best practice for showing scrollable content without using Frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say a scrollable DIV, as IFrames are just another flavor of frames. If you use IFrames, you could as well use a regular frameset...

Answer (score 0):

You can use scollable DIV with overflow:auto css property. This will use the browser scroll bars.

You might also prefer a JS based solution, which could let you use your own controls and load content dynamically with AJAX.

For example:

http://javascript.internet.com/miscellaneous/scroll-div-horizontal.html